# In java, how to swap two values in a Vector?

Tags: java, vector, swap

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Vector;
import java.util.Collections;

public class Bank implements BubbleSort{
 private Vector<Account> accounts;

 public Bank() {
  accounts = new Vector<Account>();
 }
 public void makeAccount() {
  Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
  int amount;
  while(true) {
   System.out.println("Input");
   amount = in.nextInt();
   if(amount<0)
    break;
   accounts.add(new Account(amount));

  }
 }
 public void printAccount() {
  for (int i=0;i<accounts.size();i++) {
   System.out.println(accounts.get(i).get());
  }

 }
 @Override
    public void start() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        for (int i = 0; i < accounts.size() - 1; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < accounts.size() - 1 - i; j++)
                if (isGreater(j, j + 1))
                    swap(j, j + 1);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void swap(int a, int b) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        Account temp = accounts.get(a);
        accounts.get(a) = accounts.get(b); //error
        accounts.get(b) = temp; //error
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isGreater(int a, int b) {


        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        return accounts.get(a).get() > accounts.get(b).get();
    }
}
```

In swap code, "The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable" error occurs.
How can I fix that code?
In mission, I can't use collection package.
I found a lot of codes in google or stackoverflow, but they have not been resolved.

Comment: Use set method like `accounts.set(a, accounts.get(b))`

Answer (score 0):

To change a value at a specific index in a Vector you have to use [`set()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#set(int,%20E)). Here is an example showing how to use it when swapping two values.

```
// temporarily hold onto the item at index "a"
Account temp = accounts.get(a);

// put a copy of the "b" item at the "a" location – you will briefly
// have the "b" value in two places in your vector
accounts.set(a, accounts.get(b));

// set the "b" location to have the temporary item that
// you first got from starting "a" location
accounts.set(b, temp);
```